# z-index to seperate background color and icon inside same div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

im creating a div givng background color for class="content" 
now i will describe the order in which the data has to be displayed
1, background color above that
2, icons within tag above icons
3, header and paragraph

```
<div class="col col-md-4">
                <div class="content bg-secondary" style="z-index: 0">
                    <div class="test">

                    <span>
                        <i class="fa fa-meetup fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-meetup" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 175px; z-index: 2 !important; position: absolute;"></i>
                  </span>
                        </div>
                    <div class="testt">
                    <h3 style="z-index: 4 !important;">Heading 1</h3>
                    <p style="z-index: 6 !important;"> content is entered here  entered here  entered here </p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Define the `position` different from the default value of `static`, therefor `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` wil do the job.

Comment: ya that works thans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer to this link
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/eNxGv
z-index only works when you apply for position in there attribute or they are getting the position from there, parent attribute

Comment: akash im not asking for image, im asking for background color.

i need to place a icon between background color and paragraph
and yes i have used position: absolute in style sheet

Comment: instead of background image URL, use background-color: property of CSS to change the color of the background